# Struts app resource not available http 404 error using action servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, struts

I use `netbeans 6.9` ,`struts 1.3.10` lib files placed in `/web-inf/ folder`.
resource not available `404` http error is diplayed.
did not create any directory to place seprately the action , servlet files.
al1 files are in default package.
I am novice in j2ee pls help me solving my issue..

Advance thanks..

index.jsp:

```
    <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <a href="mainpage">Main page</a>
    </body>
```

mainpage.java:

```
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet mainpage</title>");  
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<form action='strapp.action' method='post'>");
        out.println("<input type='text' name='user'/><br>");
       out.println("<input type='submit' name='Submit it'/>");
       out.println("</form>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
```

strapp.java:

```
     public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    String c=(String)request.getParameter("user");
    if(c==null)
    {
        return mapping.findForward("error");
    }
    return mapping.findForward("success");
}
 }
```

success.java:

```
       protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request,       HttpServletResponse                     response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet success</title>");  
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet success at </h1>");
        out.println("<p>Success page</p>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

    } finally { 
        out.close();
    }
   }
```

error.java:

```
       out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet error</title>");  
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Servlet error at </h1>");
        out.println("<p>Error page</p>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
```

struts-config.xml:

```
   <action-mappings>
    <action name="strapp" class="strapp" path="/strapp.action" >
    <forward name="success" path="/success.java"/>
    <forward name="error" path="/error.java"/>
        </action>
    </action-mappings>
```

web.xml:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

      <!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
      "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
      "http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>detail</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

struts-config.xml:

```
<action-mappings>
<action name="strapp" class="strapp" path="/strapp.action" >
<forward name="success" path="/success.java"/>
<forward name="error" path="/error.java"/>
    </action>
</action-mappings>
```

what is the meaning of the success.java and error.java , you must specify the servlet in the web.xml, otherwise the structs cannot not find the correct destination.
you can see the example of structs.

Comment: i already added and compiled web.xml, by adding success and error servlet.. sorry..